# Rails helper pass negative symbol as argument in self method

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

In my Rails 6, Ruby 2.7 app I'm using `ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper` and `number_to_currency` method. Everything works fine but in one place I need to have negative amount instead of positive. To do so I created two methods:

`formatters/document_amount_formatter.rb`

```
module Formatters
  # Formats the amount in a suitable form to be used in PDF creator.
  class DocumentAmountFormatter
    extend ActionView::Helpers::NumberHelper

    # The method to call.
    #
    # @return [String]
    def self.call(amount)
      number_to_currency(amount.to_f, delimiter: '.', separator: ',', format: '%n €')
    end

    def self.negative_amount(amount)
      number_to_currency(-amount.to_f, delimiter: '.', separator: ',', format: '%n €')
    end
  end
end
```

Both works well:

```
Formatters::CashbookDocumentAmountFormatter.call(cash_transactions.first.gross_amount)
=> "100,00 €"
Formatters::CashbookDocumentAmountFormatter.negative_amount(cash_transactions.first.gross_amount)
=> "-100,00 €"
```

But I'm not so sure if this is a good approach, tbh the code seems to be smelly. Is it possible to change those two methods into one? How to pass '-' or '+' as an argument inside of one of these methods?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Call `call` from within `negative_amount`.

```
    def self.negative_amount(amount)
      call(-amount)
    end
```

The next question being, why have this method at all? The caller can write `formatter.call(-amount)` just as easily and more obviously.

Note that you probably shouldn't hard-code currency formatting and instead make use if [internationalization](https://guides.rubyonrails.org/i18n.html).

Comment: Instead of two methods: `call` and `negative_amount` I want to have one method `call`. Params `amount` is a Class::Money (from gem 'money-rails') so first I need to change it to float and then add €. If I pass this argument like you wrote as `-amount` nothing really changed - the number will be still positive.

Comment: @mr_muscle "*If I pass this argument like you wrote as -amount nothing really changed - the number will be still positive.*" No, if you pass `-amount` to `call` it will receive a negative amount. Just like `call(-1.23)` gets negative 1.23. Try it.

Comment: @mr_muscle money-rails has [its own way of selecting currencies](https://github.com/RubyMoney/money-rails#currencies) which you should consider using instead.

Comment: OMG I don't know how I tested it before but you are right! I just need to pass it as -amount and it works!